# Improve sql query without using 'union'

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I want to improve this sql query without using UNION. When table_xx.uniqeId = 1 i want to use table_yy, when 2 i want to use table_ww. In fact i want this dynamic. i want to use an another table for uniqeId-table match because for future i can add extra table for example for table_xx.uniqeId = 3, use table_qq or something else. Can you suggest some idea, What can i use ?

Thanks.

```
SELECT
 xx.info,
 yy.value
FROM
 table_xx xx,
 table_yy yy
WHERE
 xx.uniqeId = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT
 xx.info,
 yy.value
FROM
 table_xx xx,
 table_ww yy
WHERE
 xx.uniqeId = 2
```

Comment: How large are the tables?  And why do you think that removing the `union all` will "improve" the query?

Comment: What a weird query, with basically two cross joins. Maybe you should give us your *actual* query, so we got a little context as well.

Comment: I think your comments written when i edit question. Now is it clear or i should give some detail ?

Comment: I still don't understand why you would do this... why not just include table_ww and include uniqueId 1 and 2?

Comment: In fact, this query is static. If i want to add new table i should use another union. But i want to do it dynamicly from a match table (uniqeId-table).This is the reason for improve.

Comment: You cannot dynamically join other tables based on an id, unless you build the query as a string and execute it, for instance with `execute immediate`. But if you do that, you can still use `union all` which will probably result in the fastest possible query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do it, provided that `value` is mandatory in yy and ww. But like Gordon Linoff already commented, a query like this doesn't necessary perform better. Most likely it won't, and it isn't much more readable as well. I would choose the union.

```
SELECT
  xx.info,
  nvl(yy.value, ww.value) as value
FROM
  table_xx xx
  LEFT JOIN table_yy yy ON xx.uniqeId = 1
  LEFT JOIN table_ww ww ON xx.uniqeId = 2
WHERE
  nvl(yy.value, ww.value) IS NOT NULL
```

But I think if the introduction of an extra xx_id also requires an extra table, it's a sign that your database structure is incorrect.

A better idea would be to add the uniqueid to the 'value' table as well, so you can easily join the right values on xx. This way, you can add extra ids and matching values as much as you like, without having to modify the database to add extra value tables.

```
SELECT
  xx.info,
  yy.value
FROM
  table_xx xx
  INNER JOIN table_yy yy ON yy.xx_uniqueid = xx.uniqueid
```

Comment: Thanks for reply GolezTrol. I'm sorry but i think i missed to say that i want a dynamic query. In this way if i want to add table_qq for uniqeId = 3, i have to edit query. Can i use a match table. Is this possible.

Comment: Yes and no. In PLSQL you can build the query as you like (as a string) and execute it. You cannot do this in SQL alone. You cannot just join extra tables based on their name. But I think the database structure is wrong, and you should actually introduce xx.uniqueid as a column in one single value table. I tried to give an example, but it's hard to give a good one and provide a nice explanation, because 'xx' and 'yy' don't give any context about you actual use case.

Comment: @BahadırYılmaz Does that answer your question?

Comment: My main purpose is writing a sql query one time and never making any change on it. The query will managed from an another table. If uniqeId has this value, use this view, else if uniqeId use this value then use this view etc. Only adding new record to this table should be enaugh. Now i undertand that from your replies, this never can. So i will use your suggestion, because joins makes query shorter, and i like short queries. Thanks.